# Generating a non-guid unique key outside of a database

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I need to create some kind of uniqueness between 'entities', but it is not a GUID, and it is not saved in a database (It is saved, however. Just not by a database).

The basic use of the key is a mere redundancy check. It does not have to be as scalable as a real 'primary key', but in the simplest terms I can think of , this is how it works.

`[receiver]` has `List<possibilities>`.

`possibilities` exist independently, but many will have the same values (impossible to predict. This is by design)

Frequently, the **receivers** list of `possibilities` will have to be emptied and then refilled (this is a business requirement).

The key is basically used to add a very lightweight redundancy check. In other words, sometimes the same possibility will be repeated, sometimes it should only appear once in the receiver's list.

I basically want to use something very light and simple. A string is sufficient. I was just wanting to figure out a modest algorithm to accomplish this. I thought about using the `GetHashCode()` method, but I am not certain about how reliable that is. Can I get some thoughts?

Comment: what is the shape of your entities? can you show the fields or describe it? GetHashCode should be overridden usually and in there you _could_ make something which would return a result kind of unique per your entities depending on properties values. Not the best hash anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use GetHashCode() at a first glance, you can probably use an [MD5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx) hash as well, obtaining less collision probability. The resulting MD5 can be stored as a 24 charachter string by encoding it base 64, let see this example:

```
    public static class MD5Gen
    {
        static MD5 hash = MD5.Create();
        public static string Encode(string toEncode)
        { 
            return Convert.ToBase64String(
            hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncode)));
        }
    }
```

with this you encode a source string in an md5 hash in string format too. You just have to write the "possibility" class in term of string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for generating Guid.

**VBScript Function to Generate a UUID/GUID**

If you are on Windows, you can use the simple VBScript below to generate a UUID. Just save the code to a file called createguid.vbs, and then run cscript createguid.vbs at a command prompt.

```
Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
NewGUID = TypeLib.Guid
WScript.Echo(left(NewGUID, len(NewGUID)-2))
Set TypeLib = Nothing
```

**Create a UUID/GUID via the Windows Command Line**

```
If you have the Microsoft SDK installed on your system, you can use the utility uuidgen.exe, which is located in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\Bin" directory
```

or try the same for more info.

[Link](http://www.somacon.com/p113.php)

I would say go for the Windows command line as it is more reliable.